# cgal boolean operation on two non-manifold Models

Tags: cgal, boolean-operations, 3d-model

I am a student doing 3D Model Processing and right now I meet one Problem:

How can i do the boolean operation on two non-manifold Models with CGAL?

Details:
The files are .stl and they have been changed into .off file. They are readable as Polyhedron, however the boolean operation by using the functions in Polygon Mesh Processing does not work any more. Then I tried the functions in Nef_Polyhedron, but it is a pity that it doesn’t work again because it is not manifold I think. So far I have no more idea about it. This task is a part of my thesis and I hope some Answer or HELP.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Please give details and code trials that you have done till now.

Comment: What version of CGAL are you using ? What boolean operation are you trying to use ?

Comment: @elimad , I use the function in Polygon Mesh Processing as "PMP::corefine_and_compute_difference(Mesh 1,Mesh2,Result,params::all_default(),params::all_default(),params::edge_is_constrained_map(is_constrained_map));" and It shows the segmentation fault, and I also tried to change the Polyhedron into Nef, but one of them can not finally be converted.

Comment: @mgimeno CGAL 4.11 and the functions is CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_difference and just Mesh1-Mesh2 after these two meshes were changed into Nef

Comment: my program can do the boolean operation with the example model in CGAL, namely blobby.off and eight.off. However, it shows the segmentation fault 11 when the program run with the CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_difference or one of the models can not be changed as Nef Polyhedron.

Comment: I see some preconditions in the doc. Are you checking they are satisfied ? If you run in Debug mode chances are you will see an assertion instead of a Segfault. It might help you figuring out the problem.

Comment: @mgimeno actually I can not understand the conditions for the boolean operation and there is no explanation online. so I just used the condition as the example online. Is there somewhere further information about that?

Comment: It says your two meshes must not have self-intersections, and must be oriented in a coherent way. Chances are those two conditions are not met. Fortunately, there is some pre-processing you can do. Look into  self_intersections(), hole_filling() and orient_to_bound_a_volume(). I hope that will help you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot you actually want your input to be Non-Manifold. Well in that case you just cannot use this function.

Comment: @mgimeno how about the functions in Nef?

Comment: @MartinLU Nef should work. I think your problem is that you loaded your file into a polyhedron and then you turned it into a Nef, but a polyhedron needs to be manifold. Use CGAL::OFF_to_nef_3() and you should be good.